# Managing dll building

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, dependencies

I have the core project with multiple dll's and number of projects, that use these dlls. 
Each time I rebuild one of core dlls, i should copy this dll to all project's folders that use it, and then mark it in TFS as "Check out for edit",to pending these changes to my team.
Is there more easy and automatic way to :

**1**)Rebuild dll to all folders that use it

**2**)"Check out for edit" changes 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think codeBase configuration might be helpful. So in this way you just need to build core project to the folder which is accessible from other solutions directly or over network. And codebase in this way might be something like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CoreAssembly"
                              culture="neutral" 
                              publicKeyToken="your public token for assembly"/>
            <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"
          href="file://SharedLibraries/Library1.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Added:**
Sorry previous idea was not very good. Just in case if anybody will have the same problem solution is pretty simple - just use internal [nuget server](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). It includes all required functionality and let you share libraries.

Comment: take a look at [this article](http://www.developer.am/c-net-platform/?page=understanding-the-codebase-element) for more details